# How can I improve this question? "How do I get the window coordinates in SwiftUI?"

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I asked this question after consulting documentation, searching for others' solutions, and using various search terms across both Google and Bing. I could not find a way to do this, so I posted a question asking how to do it. I got **no answers, three downvotes, and a comment** pointing to an answer on a slightly-related question, explaining how to patch in a separate API from a separate UI framework.

I understand that I might've been able to discover that I can patch in a separate UI framework to do what I want, and I might've found that without asking the question. However, I wanted to know how to do this within the specific UI framework in the question's title. **Why is this question considered bad, and how do I improve it?** A link to it and its text are included below for reference:

---

[How do I get the window coordinates in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61570749/3939277)

> I want to make a parallax background view, where the image behind the UI stays nearly still as the window moves around on the screen. To do this on macOS, I want to get the window's coordinates. **How do I get the window's coordinates?**

Comment: Honestly, if the user with the highest tag score on the site can't figure out a way without patching in a separate framework, chances are this is something you'll have to figure out on your own (no guarantee obviously but it's something to note). Not saying it's a bad question, honestly know nothing about the topic,... That being said.... There is not a single piece of information in your question which indicates that you've looked at documentation or, attempted to solve the problem yourself, or even searched for an answer. That may have played into voters choices.

Comment: Which part of "this question does not show any research effort" you need an explanation of?

Comment: Got it. I'll add links to the Google searches I performed. Anything else I should also do next time?

Comment: You state that you have consulted the documentation and have done extensive research, but your question shows no evidence for this whatsoever, and we can only go by what we see, what you have posted. If you've done extensive research, then show the *concrete* fruits of those efforts in your question and use it to help improve the question and make it as specific as possible. Note that I stated *concrete* efforts, not the typical "I have searched everywhere on the internet ..." statement that we too often see, and that do not help us to understand the poster's question or research.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As I said I would in my previous comment, I've just added some notes about my searches and an attempt to implement this myself.

Comment: And I'm just stating what I saw when I looked at your question.

Comment: Thank you. After adding a shortened list of searches I performed and articles I read, and an example of my most promising failed approach, is there anything else I can do to improve this question?

Comment: Don't just add links to searches. (Are you expecting us tor read them, and to know what parts of which have what to do or not with your question?) (Moreover what would be more relevant is the search phrases you used.) Summarize your research. Put everything needed in your post. Not unconnected in many places elsewhere.

Comment: @Austin *Everyone* is supposed to downvote without explanation *everywhere*. Votes are anonymous. They do not come with any explanation, beyond what it says in the tooltip.

Comment: Thank you, @philipxy. I've removed the search links, but left links to the resulting articles I researched. As I mentioned in that question, they didn't have anything I could work off of, so there's no additional example code that I can think to add

Comment: I agree, @CodyGray. I should have thought about the hovertext of the downvote button before posting my question. I also don't like the idea of metagaming the tags based on how many followers they have; I'd rather just accurately apply tags relevant to the content of the question.

Comment: What I meant about links was, give the search phrases you used in your post, so we can give you feedback on your search, and don't expect us to read a bunch of SO questions & wonder about why you think they're relevant, say/summarize what was or wasn't relevant that you extracted from them in your post. I had no idea what urls your underlined text pointed to, google pages or SO posts, because my point was I shouldn't need to follow them. (I see I just said "searches".)

Comment: Agreed, @Ben, tags should describe only the contents of the question. I think gaming the tags in order to avoid downvotes (or gain upvotes) is a bad idea, too. Things go a lot easier on Stack Overflow when you stop obsessing about downvotes. The original question had only received 3 downvotes at the time of posting this Meta question, and I think previous comments have already nailed the reason why: it didn't look like there was any evidence of research effort. It *sounded* like a trivial problem (did to me, too, not being an expert on the API), and it looked like a lazy, open-ended question.

Comment: Thanks, @CodyGray! I think I have learned enough to improve this question and avoid problems in the future. And of course I agree that even 6 downvotes isn't worth obsession; that's not what I'm doing. I'm just trying to learn and improve myself  After all, I'm only 213 points away from my first mod tools! Wouldn't wanna have those and not know how to ask a good question 