# Why was this question deleted by Community? "How do I get the window coordinates in SwiftUI?"

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, quality-improvement, vote-to-undelete

The question I'm referencing is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61570749/3939277

---

[I previously asked how to improve this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397196/3939277). However, while and before I improved it, it received 9 downvotes. Happily, while and after y'all helped me improve the question, it received 7 upvotes, totalling -2.

Yesterday, [community deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61570749/timeline#history_5d21432f-0f38-4463-b4ab-a69351575be0), with the given reason being "Scheduled: RemoveDeadQuestions".

I have a few questions:

- <s>**What is a dead question?**</s> I think that "dead" is the same as "abandoned", which is explained by [this answer on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/274106)
- <s>**Why was my question considered dead?**</s> If "dead" is the same as "abandoned", I see that this question meets the automatically-evaluated criteria for deleting abandoned questions.
- <s>**Did my improvements factor into the decision to delete the question?** If so, why weren't they sufficient to prevent it from being deleted? If not, why weren't they considered before deletion?</s> The bot which performed the decision doesn't consider things like this; only age, score, locked status, and number of answers.
- **Should I undelete the question?** If not and if the question is now a good question, should I copy-paste its content into a new question?

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this.

Comment: *"Did my improvements factor into the decision to delete the question?"* - No, *"If not, why weren't they considered before deletion?"* - Because they didn't result in the question meeting the criteria for not being dead

Comment: Note that the deletion banner on the post links [to the help center explanation of when Community deletes the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Your question met all the criteria: 30 days or older, score of -1 or lower, no answers and not locked.

Comment: Relevant Uber-meta discussion: [What should I do if I find the answer to an old question of mine that was automatically deleted as abandoned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309526), which is linked from the help center post that the deletion banner linked you to.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I now understand why it was deleted, as I mentioned in this question (I've updated it now to reflect my understanding). My last questions still stand: if the question I'm asking about is now a good question, should I undelete or repost?

Comment: You can repost.

Comment: Thank you, @SamuelLiew! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it